# Entity Framework, one-to-many, several columns

Tags: entity-framework

If I have a main table, lets say orders, and a sub table of items and the items table has a fields for item number BUT it also has a nullable (optional) field for color that applied only to certain items.  How would I update the items table, at the same time as the orders table, using Entity Framework?

Here is a code example of what I have so far. Two problems, I'm only entering one of my items and, from what my research indicates, I can't add another field to the items table?

```
    foreach (Guid c in AllItems)
    { Items.OrderItemID = Guid.NewGuid();
      ITemsOrderID = order.OrderID;
      ITems.ItemID = c;
      If (ItemID = ItemThatLetsYouChoseAColorID)
      {
          Items.ItemColorID = ColorID;
      } else {
          Items.ItemColorID = null;
      }
     }
     context.Orders.AddObject(Orders);
     context.Items.AddObject(Items);
     context.SaveChanges();
```

My Orders table gets a record inserted, and the Items gets ONE record inserted. I'm missing something basic here, I'm afraid. BTW, this is Entity Framework 4.0, which. I believe, does not require the use of EntityKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding an object to the `Items` collection only one time after the scope of your `foreach`.

Have you tested something like:

```
foreach (Guid c in AllItems)
{
    var Item = new Item();

    Item.OrderItemID = Guid.NewGuid();
    Item.OrderID = order.OrderID;
    Item.ItemID = c;
    If (ItemID = ItemThatLetsYouChoseAColorID)
    {
        Item.ItemColorID = ColorID;
    }
    else
    {
        Item.ItemColorID = null;
    }

    context.Items.AddObject(Items);
}

context.Orders.AddObject(order);
context.SaveChanges();
```

And I'm not sure to understand what you mean by

> I can't add another field to the items table

You should be more precise about what you actually expect. Insert a row, add a column in the table...? What is a "field"?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I wish to insert one row to Orders, and many rows to Items. I have tried what you've suggested above, but it inserts only the last item to the Items table. ie the AddObject(Item) isn't inserting each item, only the last one.

Comment: In re-reading your response, I see that your first sentence addressed my problem. Therefore, you answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. I had the new Item outside the foreach item loop, so was overwriting the value. Also, I need to add each one to the context. I had a hard time with this, hope it helps someone else:

```
    <-fill the order object->
    foreach (Guid i in Items)
    {
        **Items item = new Items();**
        item.ItemID = Guid.NewGuid();
        item.OrderID = order.OrderID;
        if (i == ItemWithColorGuid)
        {
            foreach (Guid c in Colors)
            {
                **Items color = new Items();**
                color.ItemsID = Guid.NewGuid();
                color.OrderID = order.orderID;
                color.itemID = g;
                color.colorID = c;
                context.item.AddObject(color);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            item.ItemID = i;
            item.ColorID = null; 
            context.item.AddObject(item);
        }                        
    }
    context.orders.AddObject(order);
    context.SaveChanges();
```